# Delphi XE2 runs very slow in VirtualBox with Windows 8.1 installed

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, performance, windows-8.1, delphi

While the whole guest Windows runs normal, Delphi XE2 is really slow, especially with code completion. And CPU utilization is near 50% though the Delphi itself does not get more than 10% during freezes.

Guest Additions are installed. VB version is 4.3.12. Host OS is Ubuntu 14.04. VT-x/AMD-V is turned on. Virtual machine has 1536 MB of RAM.

Even Visual Studio 2010 runs better. Does anyone know how to speed up Delphi? Please don't suggest to turn CC off as Delphi is useless without it.

Comment: try this IDE fix tool: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/

Comment: Wow! This helps a lot, thanks!. You can now answer this question as the tool fixes it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793683/delphi-app-has-no-debug-info-when-debugging.

Comment: you can do this. I no longer use Delphi so I don't know about this issue and if the tool fixes it. I only remembered the tool from Delphi time.